# Angular 7 Reactive forms "No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute"

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I am using reactive forms and i seem to be having issues with what would seem random form fields. Any ideas as to why this is happening is apriciated.

I have just started using angular and material 7 if that helps

Interestingly enough adding and removing elements in the form causes issues with other elements.

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name
>   attribute

TS

```
export class VolunteerApplicationPersonalStepComponent implements OnInit 
{

  public readonly form: FormGroup;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
          businessTelephoneExt: [''],
          otherTelephone: [''],
          otherTelephoneExt: [''],
        });
      }
}
```

HTML

```
    <form [formGroup]="form">

     <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput i18n-placeholder placeholder="Business Extension"
               [formControl]="form.get('businessTelephoneExt')">
      </mat-form-field>

      <app-telephone-input i18n-placeholder placeholder="Other Telephone"
                           [formControl]="form.get('otherTelephone')">
      </app-telephone-input>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput i18n-placeholder placeholder="Other Extension"
               [formControl]="form.get('otherTelephoneExt')">
      </mat-form-field>

      <br>

      <div class="group-margin group-min-width">
        <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" matStepperPrevious i18n>Previous</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext (click)="next()" i18n>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

[image]

as someone suggested .. formControlName="businessTelephoneExt"

[image]

App-Telephone Code (Note it used to have formControl NOT appFormControl)

```
export class TelephoneInputComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() public required = false;
  @Input() public placeholder = '';
  @Input() public appFormControl: NgControl;

  constructor() {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
  }
}



<mat-form-field>
  <input
    matInput
    type="tel"
    [required]="required"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    [formControl]="appFormControl">

  <mat-hint i18n>Please enter digits only</mat-hint>

  <mat-error
    *ngIf="appFormControl.hasError('phone')"
    i18n>Invalid phone (requires 10 digits)
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: you tried `formControlName="businessTelephoneExt"`?

Comment: that made no difference

Comment: did you try commenting out your `app-telephone-input` custom controls, to ensure its not an issue with that?

Comment: it does seem like custom components are causing it

Comment: renamed to appFormControl and now its fine... what is the deal with component naming conventions?

Comment: if renaming to appFormControl worked, that would be because your custom control was looking for an input with that name (I suspect).  In general custom controls require certain specific hooks (ie NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR) to work with the standard forms hooks ie the `formControl` tag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

seems you cannot have a @Input() named formControl

Answer (score 3):

One little thing I see is this:

```
  <app-telephone-input i18n-placeholder placeholder="Other Telephone"
                       [formControl]="form.get('otherTelephone')">
  </app-telephone-input>
```

So it should be:

```
  <app-telephone-input i18n-placeholder placeholder="Other Telephone"
                       [appFormControl]="form.get('otherTelephone')">
  </app-telephone-input>
```

If you want to create a custom form controler you should implement ControlValueAccessor interface

```
ControlValueAccessor {
  writeValue(obj: any): void
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void
  ...
}
```

If you implement ControlValueAccessor interface only you can bind property  formControl

Answer (score 1):

@ricardo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53784497/930875) is not correct

You can have a @Input() named formControl when using the ControlValueAccessor interface, it is likely you have not added a NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR token to your providers. Something like:

```
export const VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyComponent),
    multi: true,
};

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
    providers: [VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
```

Comment: thanks for the update, i wonder if this was around in v7

Comment: Also, make sure it's in a module - the same error can happen when it's not!

Answer (score 0):

Remove otherTelephone formcontrol from parent component and add otherTelephone from child component

```
export class VolunteerApplicationPersonalStepComponent implements OnInit 
{

  public readonly form: FormGroup;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
          businessTelephoneExt: [''],
          otherTelephoneExt: [''],
        });
      }
}
```

Using controlContainer to provide parent form instance to child component then inject FormGroupDiretive to get parent form instance

**apptelephoneinput.component.html**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-telephone-input',
  templateUrl: './app-telephone-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-telephone-input.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective 
}]
})
export class TelephoneInputComponent implements OnInit {   
  @Input() public required = false;
  @Input() public placeholder = '';
  childForm;
  constructor(private parentF: FormGroupDirective) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.childForm = this.parentF.form;
    this.childForm.addControl('otherTelephone', new FormControl(''))
  }

}
```

**app-telephone-input.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    matInput
    type="tel"
    [required]="required"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    formControl="otherTelephone">
```

Sample example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fktkdk